# How to redirect url with subdomain in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

we have a site which developed in CodeIgniter. And also we have the subdomain.

```
www.mmm.com
www.admin.mmm.com
```

Now we want to redirect URL to the subdomain. 
ex: `mmm.com/result/admin/login` : this URL will be open by sub domain (`admin.mmm.com`) .

How can we do it?

Comment: So `mmm.com/result/admin/login` will redirect to `admin.mmm.com`?

Comment: this url (mmm.com/result/admin/login) will be redirect to admin.mmm.com

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

```
redirect($uri = '', $method = 'auto', $code = NULL)
```

In your case you would do the following in the controller `result` at the function `admin`. In that function you should have a code checking if the parameter `login` is given as the first parameter. Add the following in that piece of code:

```
redirect('admin.mmm.com');
```

Explanation from codeigniter documentation (https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect)

> redirect($uri = '', $method = 'auto', $code = NULL)
>
> Does a “header redirect” to the URI specified. If you specify the full
>   site URL that link will be built, but for local links simply providing
>   the URI segments to the controller you want to direct to will create
>   the link. The function will build the URL based on your config file
>   values.
>
> The optional second parameter allows you to force a particular
>   redirection method. The available methods are auto, location and
>   refresh, with location being faster but less reliable on IIS servers.
>   The default is auto, which will attempt to intelligently choose the
>   method based on the server environment.
>
> The optional third parameter allows you to send a specific HTTP
>   Response Code - this could be used for example to create 301 redirects
>   for search engine purposes. The default Response Code is 302. The
>   third parameter is only available with location redirects, and not
>   refresh